# Using the iphone camera

Tags: iphone, camera

What is the best way to use the iphone camera in your app?

I would want to allow the user to take an image, then either retake or save.

Where do the pics get saved to? Can I assign a name to a captured image?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `UIImagePickerController`. See Apple's documentation for information on how to use it: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

As for where the pictures get saved: They don't get saved anywhere automatically. You have to implement the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` and then store the `UIImage` to wherever you want, with whatever file name you want, using `NSFileManager` methods.

Comment: I want to take images, not pick from existing. Doesnt the above just pick an image from already captured images?

Comment: The name is somewhat misleading. `UIImagePickerController` is used to take pictures from the camera as well. See the `sourceType` property in the documentation.